# How to fill a div width from the right to left?

Tags: jquery

I am using progress bars to accomplish an update of count with jquery.countTo. The default fill method of a div width is left to right, is there any way to achieve filling from right to left? I am using the onUpdate function of countTo.

```
$('#cat-'+catNum+' span#asp-1-ev').countTo({
                from: 1,
                to: asp1EV,
                speed:asp1EV*speed,
                onUpdate: function (value) {
                    percent=Math.round(((value/catVotes)*100),2);
                    $('#cat-'+catNum+' span#asp-1-pt').html(percent);
                    $('#cat-'+catNum+' div#asp-1-bar').attr('style','width:'+percent+'%');
                },
            });
```

Comment: please test style="float:right;" on div element

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want only use jquery.countTo, but this JS code works smothness:

You just need call `move(p, e)` function, and pass the percentage and the element to show.

```js
function move(percent, element) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(element);   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= percent) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<h1>Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>

<button onclick="move(88, 'myBar')">Go to 88%</button>
```

#### Reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_3